# Do sets have dimensions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a very basic question

Let $x_1, x_2$ be real and distinct numbers

Does the set $\mathcal{X} = \{x_1, x_2\}$ have a dimension (e.g., $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Comment: A plain set probably doesn't have a reasonable notion of dimension to it. However, if this set is given a *topology*, then there is a notion of [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension), in fact [multiple such](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension#Topological_spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are looking for in this case is cardinality. The cardinality of a set is the number of elements in the set; in this case, the cardinality is $2$. In group theory, the cardinality is usually called the order of the group, but regardless, the word cardinality is sufficient.

Comment: The cardinality is at most 2: what if $x_1=x_2$?

Comment: @amd sets cannot have repeat elements. If $x_1=x_2$ then the set is just written $\{x_1\}$.

Comment: In pretty much any standard set theory, $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$. It’s only a convention that each unique element is listed only once when writing out the set explicitly. There’s nothing in the question that precludes $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: Not at all. That identity appears in several text books on my shelf and says exactly the opposite: that sets _do not_ have repeated elements, regardless of how many times you might choose to write down the same element in a set constructor.

Comment: @amd Every definition that I've seen for a set is that a set is a collection of distinct objects. Please send references my way as I'm genuinely confused. The textbooks that I refer to define different data structures to allow for repeated elements.

Comment: Don’t confuse the object with the notation. A set is not the string of symbols used to denote it.

Comment: @amd I'm even more confused with that last comment: I said the number of elements in a set defines the cardinality. The set $\{a, a\}=\{a\}$. But I could write an infinite number of $a$'s. So it does not make sense to say that the set $\{a, a \ldots, a\}$ has an infinite number of elements. You are declaring the set, but the actual set has a single element, $a$.

Comment: The string “$\{a\}$” is not a set; it is a _description_ of a set. This notation describes a set via a list of (descriptions of) its elements. Membership is binary: an object either is or is not an element of a given set. The strings “$\{a\}$” and “$\{a,a\}$” are different descriptions of the same set. Just as having your name called twice during roll call doesn’t mean that you attended the same class session twice, listing the same element more than once in a _description_ of a set doesn’t increase the set’s cardinality.

Comment: You can see this identity put to practical use [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition), for instance.